# Every time I open Terminal, I hear a computerized voice telling me "You've been trolled." What is likely causing this?

Tags: terminal

Every time I open Terminal, I hear a computerized voice telling me "You've been trolled." What is likely causing this?

I'm on a mac if that helps.

Comment: There's an entry in your terminals profile file that'll execute on every terminal "login". Search for "You've been trolled" in your profile file and remove it

Comment: Where's my terminals profile file?

Comment: In your home directory. Should be something like `.profile` or `.bash_profile`

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Someone added say "You've been trolled" to the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some l33t hacker (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3855197/dawson-botsford) added `say "you've been trolled"` to the beginning of my `.bash_profile` file. So I just removed the line